# Curl : how can i create xml file with url parameters

Tags: curl

i having below url.

`curl -v -X POST -d "FROM_AGENT=true&LOGIN_ID=test&PASSWORD=passwd" https://accounts.test.com/login`

I want to hidden below parameters using the above command.

`FROM_AGENT=true&LOGIN_ID=test&PASSWORD=passwd`

how can i create xml file (using this params `FROM_AGENT`,`LOGIN_ID`,`PASSWORD`)

i browse and get below command for xml input of curl. but i dont know how can create xml file

`curl -v -X POST -d @test.xml https://accounts.test.com/login`

Comment: `@test.xml` means you are uploading `test.xml` file. Before uploading check if acconts.test.com supports xml file? Also check if they have any API reference. Everything should be written there.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im my api full url is https://accounts.zoho.com/login?FROM_AGENT=true&LOGIN_ID=test&PASSWORD=test . it will return some response.